# Error al invocar this en un modelo de mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un modelo para MongoDB con mongoose. Me estoy apoyando con Typescript para definirlo. Tengo un problema por que cuando declaro una propiedad y quiero meter una función de validación haciendo referencia a otra propiedad, TS me arroja un error

> Property 'gender' does not exist on type 'SchemaTypeOpts |
>   Schema | SchemaType'.   Property 'gender' does not exist on type
>   'Schema'.ts(2339)

Este es mi código

```
import mongo from 'mongoose'

const schema = new mongo.Schema({


   name: {
    type: String,
    match:  [ /^[a-zA-Z]{2,35}$/, 
            'El es requerido y debe tener una longitud de 2-35 caracteres' ]
},

lastName: {
    type: String,
    match:  [ /^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$/, 
            'El es requerido y debe tener una longitud de 2-50 caracteres' ]
},

email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [ true, 'Ya existe un correo electrónico registrado' ],
    match:  [ /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'El formato del correo es incorrecto'
    ]
},

userName: {
    type: String,
    unique: [ true, 'Ya existe este nombre de usuario'],
    match:  [ /^[a-zA-Z]{5,15}$/, 
            'El es requerido y debe tener una longitud de 5-15 caracteres' ]
},

phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    match: [ /^[0-9]{10}$/, 
           'El formato del número telefónico es incorrecto' ]
},

gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['H', 'M'],
    default: 'H'
},

department: {
    type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Department'
},

role: {
    type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role'
},

photo: {
    type: String,
    default: function() {
        return this.gender === 'M' ? 'profile_male.png' : 'profile_female.png'
    }
},

sign: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'Fatal: No se creo correctamente la contraseña']
},

status: {
   type: String,
   enum: ['activo', 'inactivo'],
   default: 'activo'
},

createdBy: {
   type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
},

createdDate: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
},

changes: [
   {
       date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
       user: { type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
   }
]

}, { collection: 'users' })

export const UserModel = mongo.model( 'User', schema )
```

Intenté hacer [esta validación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) de ejemplo en la documentación oficial de mongoose

Comment: Hola. Esa no es una validación, es un valor por defecto. Intenta crear la función por fuera del schema y luego llámala sin los parentesis. De esta manera: `default: miFuncionDefault` Me dices como te va.

Comment: Ok, pero como le paso el parámetro de `gender`?

Comment: Ok, no puedes de esa manera, tienes que usar los pre hooks. Un `Schema.pre('save')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la documentacion de mongoose:

> ## [Default functions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions)
>
> Tambien puedes definir la opcion del esquema por defecto a travez de una funcion. Mongoose ejecutara la función y retornara ese valor por defecto.

```
var schema = new Schema({   
title: String,   
date: {
    type: Date,
    // `Date.now()` returns the current unix timestamp as a number
    default: Date.now   
 } 
});
```

---

## [Save/Validate Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order)

Para lograr hacer lo que quieres debes definir un pre hook:

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.photo= this.gender === 'M' ? 'profile_male.png' : 'profile_female.png'
    //Continúa con la ejecución del middleware. 
    next();
});
```

Mas informacion [aqui](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)